# ControlsFX - How to use updated fontawesome as glyphs?

Tags: javafx-8, controlsfx

I am using this code to create a glyph from the most recent fontawesome that is not available on controlsfx:

```
InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("fa-solid-900.ttf");
GlyphFontRegistry.register("FA-SOLID", resourceAsStream, 14);
GlyphFont glyphFont = GlyphFontRegistry.font("FA-SOLID");

imageBuy.setGraphic(glyphFont.create('\uf291').size(28));
```

But it does not show the icon, instead it shows a square.

It should show a shopping basket:
https://fontawesome.com/icons/shopping-basket?style=solid

I have got fa-solid-900.ttf from the latest fontawesome download at this time (5.0.8).

Any help?

Thanks.